# adding end values in a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with the following structure.

Is there a function which can combine elements together, summing the totals?

Thanks for any pointers on how to achieve this. I've included a section of the array here, and then lower down the hopeful result.

I can achieve this via creating a second array as I reinterate over a php mysql query, but this doesn't feel like a very efficient way of doing things.

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [Y01MA] => Array
                (
                    [O] => Array
                        (
                            [F] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => 4
                                    [2] => 6
                                    [3] => 1
                                )

                            [M] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => 5
                                    [2] => 5
                                )

                        )

                    [P] => Array
                        (
                            [F] => Array
                                (
                                    [2] => 4
                                    [3] => 6
                                    [4] => 1
                                )

                            [M] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => 1
                                    [2] => 4
                                    [3] => 5
                                )

                        )

                )

            [Y01MB] => Array
                (
                    [O] => Array
                        (
                            [F] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => 7
                                    [2] => 2
                                )

                            [M] => Array
                                (
                                    [1] => 11
                                    [2] => 1
                                    [3] => 1
                                )

                        )

                    [P] => Array
                        (
                            [F] => Array
                                (
                                    [2] => 3
                                    [3] => 6
                                )

                            [M] => Array
                                (
                                    [2] => 3
                                    [3] => 9
                                    [4] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
```

Ideally what I would then end up with is something like this

Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [O] => Array
                (
                    [F] => Array
                        (
                            [1] => 18
                            [2] => 2
                            [3] => 0
                            [4] => 0
                        )

```
                [M] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 23
                        [2] => 0
                        [3] => 0
                        [4] => 0
                    )

            )

        [P] => Array
            (
                [F] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 1
                        [2] => 11
                        [3] => 7
                        [4] => 1
                    )

                [M] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 4
                        [2] => 11
                        [3] => 8
                        [4] => 0
                    )

            )

    )
```

Comment: Do you need to group them in any way at all or just every value in the array.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: ideally I'd like to be able to work out how many [1] [2] [3] [4] there are for each [M] and [F]

Comment: Can you give a clear example of the output you want in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a recursive sum of array.

You can achieve this by a recursively reducing array using [`array_reduce`](https://php.net/array_reduce) function.

```
function sumRecursive($carry, $item) {
    if(is_array($item)){
        return array_reduce($item, 'sumRecursive', $carry);
    }
    return $carry+$item ;
}
$sum = sumRecursive(0, $arr);
```

Here's example working code: https://3v4l.org/FuGtf

Other way would to be utilize [`RecursiveArrayIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivearrayiterator.php) and [`RecursiveIteratorIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursiveiteratoriterator.php) to iterate over the first one. ;-)

```
$sum = array_sum(
    iterator_to_array(
        new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
            new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr)
        ),
        false
    )
);
```

Working code: https://3v4l.org/gEB6q